# Airflow fails to create table from custom datamodel on initdb

Tags: airflow

I'm developing a custom airflow plugin that should show a (custom) table from metadata database

```py
class CampaignModel(Base, LoggingMixin):
    __tablename__ = "campaigns"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    campaign_name = Column(String(ID_LEN), unique=True)

class CampaignsView(ModelView):
    page_size = 50

v = CampaignsView(CampaignModel, settings.Session(), name="Campaigns")

class CampaignEditorPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "campaigns_plugin"
    ...
    admin_views = [v]
    ...
```

Airflow starts correctly and loads the plugin. But it will not create / register my new table in `CampaignModel` on a `airflow initdb` or `airflow resetdb`.

How do I correctly register the table such that SQLAlchemy creates it on *initdb*?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a table to the Airflow db with a) an Alembic migration or b) SQLAlchemy ORM.

a) Migration using Alembic

Adds code to the Airflow repo.

```py
# 1. Create a migration file
cd airflow_dir/airflow/
alembic revision -m "create new_table table"

# 2. Add upgrade and downgrade instructions to the generated migration Python file.
## airflow_dir/airflow/migrations/versions/0a2a5b66e19d_add_new_table_table.py

import sqlalchemy as sa
from alembic import op

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = 'xxxxxxxxx'
down_revision = 'xxxxxxxxx'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None


def upgrade():
    op.create_table('new_table',
        sa.Column('task_id', sa.String(length=250, **COLLATION_ARGS), nullable=False),
        sa.Column('dag_id', sa.String(length=250, **COLLATION_ARGS), nullable=False)

def downgrade():
    op.drop_table('new_table')


# 3. Run the migration
alembic upgrade head
```

b) SQLAlchemy ORM

Can be used in an Airflow plugin on your instance directory separate from the Airflow repo.

```py
from airflow import settings
from sqlalchemy import Column, Index, String
from airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin import LoggingMixin
from airflow.utils.session import create_session

class NewModel(Base, LoggingMixin):
    __tablename__ = "new_table"
    id = Column(String(ID_LEN), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(ID_LEN), unique=True)


# Create new table in Airflow db
NewModel.__table__.create(settings.engine, checkfirst=True)

# Create object
new_object = NewModel(id='1', name='my name')

# Write to Airflow db
with create_session() as session:
    session.add(new_object)
    session.commit()
```

Answer (score -1):

Although not through `initdb` or `resetdb` adding `CampaignModel.__table__.create(settings.engine, checkfirst=True)` after defining the class causes the table to be created when the module is loaded if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23746567)

Comment: clarified my answer